# why TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-chinese') can't use?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I want to do chinese Textual Similarity with huggingface:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-chinese')
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-chinese')
```

It doesn't work, system report errors:

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-chinese were not used when initializing TFBertForSequenceClassification: ['nsp___cls', 'mlm___cls']
- This IS expected if you are initializing TFBertForSequenceClassification from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPretraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing TFBertForSequenceClassification from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Some weights of TFBertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-chinese and are newly initialized: ['classifier', 'dropout_37']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
```

But I can use huggingface to do name entity:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-chinese')
model = TFBertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-chinese")
```

Does that mean huggingface haven't done chinese sequenceclassification? If my judge is right, how to sove this problem with colab with only 12G memory？

Comment: Most of the offical models doesn't have pretrained output layers. The weights are randomly initialized. You need to train them for your task. It is not an error btw. Just a warning.

Comment: @cronoik, I just used the pretrained model "BertModel.from_pretrained("hfl/chinese-roberta-wwm-ext")" and got the same warning message. Do I need to train it on my own data as well? I just need the pretrained embedding vector for generic text.

Comment: @marlon You do not need to train it when you are just interested in the sentence embedding vector, but keep in mind that [BERT does not produce meaningful sentence representations](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/164#issuecomment-441324222) that could be used for cosine similarity or something like that because it requires all dimension to have the same scale. You may want to finetune your model or look at the [sentence-transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) lib instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple. The model has not been fine-tuned for the Sequence classification task hence when you try to load the 'bert-base-chinese' model over a Sequence classification model. It updates the rest of the layers ['nsp___cls', 'mlm___cls'] randomly.
And it's a warning which means the model will be giving random results due to the random last layer initialization.

BTW @andy you didn't upload the output for token classification? It should also show a similar warning but with ['classifier'] layer as randomly initiated.

Do use a fine-tuned model, else you would need to fine-tune this loaded model.